# Python only returning first line of list

Tags: python

When attempting to use this script in conjunction with cat command, I am only getting the first entry, rather than all of them. here is the script:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip() #strip out carriage return
    key_value  = line.split(",")   #split line, into key and value, returns a list
    key_in     = key_value[0]
    value_in   = key_value[1]

#print key_in
if(value_in.isdigit()==True):
    print('%s\t%s' % (key_in, value_in)) 
elif(value_in == 'ABC'):
    print('%s\t%s' % (key_in, value_in))
```

I am then running cat command on the target files and the script. Thoughts?

Comment: I imagine you are getting the last not the first, your if and print are outside the loop

Comment: Can you give an example of your input, and the output you expect for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation looks incorrect. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip() #strip out carriage return
    key_value  = line.split(",")   #split line, into key and value, returns a list
    key_in     = key_value[0]
    value_in   = key_value[1]

    #print key_in
    if(value_in.isdigit()==True):
        print('%s\t%s' % (key_in, value_in)) 
    elif(value_in == 'ABC'):
        print('%s\t%s' % (key_in, value_in))
```